# Graphical problems with minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

All of a sudden, the colors in minecraft are wrong. [image: Minecraft colors wrong]

I installed latest driver of my AMD Radeon HD6890 and should have latest version of java installed. Anyone knows what I can do about this? If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Wear 3D glasses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like 3D mode is activated.

To disable, go into options (press <kbd>ESC</kbd>) → Video settings → disable 3D Analgyph.

Comment: this indeed solved the problem :)